# What is the minimum value of $(x_1-x_2)^2+(12+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2})^2$?

Tags: calculus, optimization, conic-sections, maxima-minima

**Question**: What is $$\min \left[(x_1-x_2)^2+\left(12+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2}\right)^2 \right] $$ where  $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R .$

I thought that let $x_1=x$ and $x_2=y$ and then simply minimise the function.
I got $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+12(1-x^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{y+2-x+12(y)^{\frac{-1}{2}}}$$

Which in putting zero gave me $$y_o^2=\frac{144}{1-x_o^2}$$ Now how to proceed further? $(x_o,y_o)$:Critical point's coordinate

Note: This question is under conics sections heading. Am I missing something obvious form conics basics or is it completely calculus approach?

Given answer is $4\sqrt5-1$

[image: Source of the question]

Comment: @Moo Please see that These $(x,y) $ in the last equation are points themselves

Comment: @Moo Please see the edit

Comment: The question is all what I've written @Moo

Comment: Firstly, you have a function of _two_ variables, so you don't have "$y$ as a function of $x$". What you have is "$z$ as a function of $x,y$". So to find "critical points" you would have to take both partial derivatives and set them to zero (good luck with that!). Secondly, it's very likely that you are not giving the correct statement of the problem. Please check it carefully (so as not to waste everyone's time). Better yet, tell us the source of the problem. Is it from a book? If so, which book, which chapter, which exercise?

Comment: Sure. @quasi Will be uploading the source in a min.

Comment: To minimize $f$, $x_2$ is at least 2. $x_1$ can be set to equal 1 to minimize the 2 terms involved. You can then minimize the new function in terms of $x_2$.

Comment: @delt3 Can you please elaborate? I seem to have lost my senses now. Would  appreciate some detailing to that.

Comment: To reduce the term $(12+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2})^2$, you show make $x_2$ large, so $x_2$ should be bigger than 2. Then try to see $x_1=1$. That's it.

Comment: I see that you uploaded an image -- thanks for that. But then I think the source is in error -- probably a typo. There's no way that function has such a low minimum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easily shown that all of the choices are wrong . . .

Let $f$ be defined by

$$f(x_1,x_2) = (x_1-x_2)^2+\left(12+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2}\right)^2$$

Then the domain of $f$ is the set of all pairs $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$$-1 \le x_1 \le 1$$

$$x_2 \ge 0$$

Note that all of the choices for the minimum value of $f$ are less than $10$.

Suppose $f(x_1,x_2) < 10,\,$ for some $x_1,x_2$ in the domain of $f$.$\\[8pt]$

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\,&f(x_1,x_2) < 10\\[4pt]
\implies\; &(x_1-x_2)^2+\left(12+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2}\right)^2 < 10\\[4pt]
\implies\; &\left(12+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2}\right)^2 < 10\\[4pt]
\implies\; &\left|12+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2}\right|< \sqrt{10}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &\left|12+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2}\right|< 4\\[4pt]
\implies\; &-4 < 12+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2}< 4\\[4pt]
\implies\; &-16 - \sqrt{1-x_1^2} < -\sqrt{4x_2}< -8 - \sqrt{1-x_1^2}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &-17 < -\sqrt{4x_2}< -8\\[4pt]
\implies\; &8 < \sqrt{4x_2} < 17\\[4pt]
\implies\; &64 < 4x_2 < 289\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x_2 > 16\\[4pt]
\implies\; &|x_1-x_2| > 15\\[4pt]
\implies\; &(x_1 - x_2)^2 > 15^2\\[4pt]
\implies\; &f(x_1,x_2) > 15^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

contradiction.$\\[8pt]$

Assuming I computed it correctly, the actual minimum value of $f$ is the real root $v$ of

$$v^3-433v^2+65088v-2822400 = 0$$

which yields $v \approx 72.41145380$.

The minimum is realized when $(x_1,x_2) = (1,u),\,$ where $u$ is the real root of

$$u(u+1)^2 = 144$$

which yields $u \approx 4.596909378$.

Comment: But $f(1,4)=73$?

Comment: Hmmm .. right, I see that. So the minimum is not at (1,0) or (-1,0) as I thought I had computed. I'll fool with it. In the meantime, I'll edit out my claim of min = 145. Thanks.

Comment: @quasi Actually one of my friends actually proved that answer is $B$. Lemme share how. He considered the $f(x_1,x_2)$ to be actually distance between two points as : ${(distance)}^2=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2  $ where $y_1=12+\sqrt{1-{x_1}^2} $ and $y_2=\sqrt{4x_2}$ . Thus getting two curves $(y_1-12)^2+{x_1}^2=1$ and ${y_2}^2+4x_2=0$ which is simply a circle and a parabola. By consequently solving via concept of common normal, we do get the option $B$

Comment: @TheDeadLegend: Firstly, you have a typo: It should be $y_2^2-4x_2=0$.

Comment: @TheDeadLegend: Secondly, while your friend's interpretation of the problem as a distance minimization problem is a very good way to approach the problem, your friend missed a key point. You do get a parabola, but you don't get a full circle -- you only get the upper semicircle. The closest point of the semicircle to the parabola is the point $(1,0)$. If you then proceed to minimize the square of the distance from the point $(1,0)$ to the parabola, you'll see that the answer is not B or any of the other choices. The correct answer is the one I posted.

Comment: But based on your friend's idea, the problem was probably meant to be: What is the minimum value of 
$$(x_1-x_2)^2+(12-\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2})^2$$
And for the _above_ question, your friend's reasoning works perfectly, and the answer would indeed be "B".

Comment: @quasi Yes. indeed. (It kinda made sense 'coz it was under conic section heading

Comment: Actually, even with the "fixed" version, a little more care is needed. If the question was: What is the minimum value of
$$(x_1-x_2)^2+(12-\sqrt{1-x_1^2}-\sqrt{4x_2})^2$$
the answer is not $4\sqrt{5}-1$ but rather $\left(4\sqrt{5}-1\right)^2 \approx 63.11145618$ Thus, the answer is not $B$, but I guess you could say that the answer is $B^2$

Comment: @quasi I cannot understand that using your answer, we get minimum value absolutely greater than $12$, but in this Desmos sketch, we see values near $10$ are achieved. Please correct me if its wrong, thanks. Here's the plot: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pk4uzjvas8

Comment: @samjoe: You forgot to square the second parenthesized expression. Also, inside the second parenthesized expression, there should by two variables, not one.

Comment: Thanks quasi, already upvoted! How did you compute minima?

Comment: @samjoe: This problem was from last year. and I didn't save the work. But if I get a chance (tomorrow or the day after), I'll revisit the problem. I'll let you know when I've reworked it.

Comment: @samjoe: Ok, I've reworked it (using Maple for the algebra). Do you have access to Maple?

Comment: @quasi Thanks! but I don't have Maple. Actually this question was on my paper too, so I got curious! I think its not possible (feasible rather) manually

Comment: @samjoe: Right, but the question is almost surely a misprint. With a minor change, the problem is really nice, and can be done by hand

Comment: @samjoe: If you're interested in discussing the problem, perhaps we could start a private chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76361/discussion-between-samjoe-and-quasi).

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha also thinks the source is in error. When telling it to minimize $f(x,y)=(x - y)^2 + (12 + \sqrt{1 - x^2} - 2 \sqrt{y})^2$, it returns the function value of $\frac{1}{3}(433 - \frac{7775}{\sqrt[3]{(140112\sqrt{2919}} - 7538831)} + \sqrt[3]{140112\sqrt{2919} - 7538831})$, which does not seem to be the answer they desired.

Answer (score 0):

For minimum of $f(t,r)=[(t-r)^2+(12-\sqrt{1-t^2}-\sqrt{4r})^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for all permissible values of t and r, you can observe a hint which says for all permissible values implying a conic/geometrical approach (real axes).

Replace t and r with x and y respectively, to get the following;

$$f(x,y)=[(x-y)^2+(12-\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{4y})^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Now on observation, we can conclude it's the distance between a circle $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ and $y^2=4x$, we need to find the minimum distance between these two conics.

The shortest distance between two conics is along their common normal.

Take the slope form of the normal of the parabola; $y=mx-2m-m^3$ and this normal passes through a parametric point $P(m^2,-2m)$ as well as the centre of the circle.

On passing the given points through the normal, we get $m=2$ and consecutively the parametric point P as $(4,4)$.

Refer for better understanding here - https://byjus.com/jee/equations-of-normal-to-a-parabola/

The minimum distance of point $P(4,4)$ (on parabola) to the circle is measured as $CP-r$, where C is the centre of the circle $C(0,1)$ and r is the radius=1, substituting(in distance formula between two points), we get the minimum as you require; $4\sqrt 5-1$